# PHP - Explode list variables to array

Tags: php, arrays, list, explode

i have a small problem with the explode function. I have a string like this:

```
$response:"online,ksksuems,3428939,670605083faeb7750e1afc1010f0f66f8ef0025a,File1.zip
offline,iwksksiw,,, offline,kdlsiwie,,, offline,jdmsmwus,,,
online,uekseks,4023702,37d97c816afdfb10857057d870e74e8774e2bf8a,File2.zip
online,jwksjwa,8860421,20b5e3154653f24963d005cd873917d3cc0a0fe2,File3.rar
online,jsusneus,4912753,9489a47bac4d2a4f7f6810cb37f60924ef48fc48,File4.rar
online,udjdjsis,1177526,5d1da2a1aebae206908ef6d88105f5272ab423e0,File5.zip"
```

Now I wanted to use the explode function:

```
list($fileStatus, $fileId, $fileSize, $fileSha1, $fileName) = explode(",", $response);
```

But I will only get 1 response, if I print the content of $fileStatus. My Question now, how can i get an array for each variable? So that i have `"array(ksksuems => online, iwksksiw => offline);"` ?

Comment: You have a syntax error.  Did you mean `$response=`?  Is your data truly line separated?  Why not read each line in (or split on the lines) before splitting by commas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work -

```
$arr = Array();
$lines = explode("\r\n", $response);

//print the exploded lines here.
var_dump($lines);
/*
    Expected output -
    array
      0 => string 'online,ksksuems,3428939,670605083faeb7750e1afc1010f0f66f8ef0025a,File1.zip' (length=74)
      1 => string 'offline,iwksksiw,,, offline,kdlsiwie,,, offline,jdmsmwus,,,' (length=59)
      2 => string 'online,uekseks,4023702,37d97c816afdfb10857057d870e74e8774e2bf8a,File2.zip' (length=73)
      3 => string 'online,jwksjwa,8860421,20b5e3154653f24963d005cd873917d3cc0a0fe2,File3.rar' (length=73)
      4 => string 'online,jsusneus,4912753,9489a47bac4d2a4f7f6810cb37f60924ef48fc48,File4.rar' (length=74)
      5 => string 'online,udjdjsis,1177526,5d1da2a1aebae206908ef6d88105f5272ab423e0,File5.zip' (length=74)
*/


foreach($lines as $line){
    list($fileStatus, $fileId, $fileSize, $fileSha1, $fileName) = explode(",", $line);
    $arr[$fileId] = $fileStatus;
}
var_dump($arr);
/*
    OUTPUT-
    array
      'ksksuems' => string 'online' (length=6)
      'iwksksiw' => string 'offline' (length=7)
      'uekseks' => string 'online' (length=6)
      'jwksjwa' => string 'online' (length=6)
      'jsusneus' => string 'online' (length=6)
      'udjdjsis' => string 'online' (length=6)
*/
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems like a good solution, but if I try it, it will only give me the first line: `array(1) { 'ksksuems' => string(6) "online" }`

Comment: Oh... It seems to be working on my end. Even here is it is working - http://codepad.org/QfTKGcGl

Comment: ...That's strange, if i copy your code, i will see this in my browser: (http://modplace.de/mp-php/explode.php)

Comment: Hmm... Try echoing the code after the explode statement. I think the content in $response variable is different.

Comment: Now I have echoed the $response variable after the first explode statement.

Comment: I've copied the edit: modplace.de/mp-php/explode.php I can provide you the FTP Login data, that you could make changes, if you want send me a email to marco@modplace.de

Comment: Hmm, you string does not seem to be separating by newlines. Try using `$lines = explode("\n", $response);` instead of this `$lines = explode("\r\n", $response);`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `explode()` on your response to put the individual responses into an array and then loop through it to get each other values.

Assuming a the new line character of `\n` as the separator:

```
$responses = explode("\n", $response);
foreach ($responses as $resp) {
    list($fileStatus, $fileId, $fileSize, $fileSha1, $fileName) = explode(",", $resp);
    // do stuff
}
```